# Null Pointer Exception in writing java object to csv file

Tags: java, json, csv

I want to convert Json file to CSV file. I passed data from json to java object then I try to write Java object to CSV file but it gives NPE. It probably not correctly gets the data from JSON. I'm not sure what it is.

**Class for reading json to java object**

```
public Student convertJson(File jsonFile)  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Student std;

    try{
        std = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile),Student.class);
        return std;

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Class for converting object to csv**

```
private final String SEPARATOR = ", ";
public void toCSV(List<Student> student) {

try{
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("group.csv"),"UTF-8"));

    for(Student std: student){

        StringBuffer oneLine = new StringBuffer();
        oneLine.append(std.getEmail());
        oneLine.append(SEPARATOR);
        oneLine.append(std.getName());
        oneLine.append(SEPARATOR);
        oneLine.append(std.getScoreGroup());
        oneLine.append(SEPARATOR);
        oneLine.append(std.getCommentGroup());

        bw.write(oneLine.toString());
        bw.newLine();

    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Main**

```
 File newfile = new File(pathName);
    List<File> files= file.findFile(newfile);  // step 1 find files and return arralist of files
    System.out.println(files);




    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(); // array list of objects Student
    ReadJson fiel = new ReadJson();             // parses passed json file and returns Student file

    List<Group> info = new ArrayList<>();
    java.util.Collections.sort(info);

    for(int i=0;i<files.size();i++){
        Student temp = fiel.convertJson(new File(files.get(i).getName()));
        students.add(temp);
    }


    ConvertJSONFiles json = new ConvertJSONFiles();
    json.toCSV(students);
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ca.cmpt213.as2.ConvertJSONFiles.toCSV(ConvertJSONFiles.java:16)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63683', transport: 'socket'

**New problem**: Now it says it cannot read because there should be object not array.

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 13 path $.group
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:826)
>       at ca.cmpt213.as2.ReadJson.convertJson(ReadJson.java:17)
>       at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:36)

Comment: post the exception stack trace

Comment: @PankajGadge posted.

Answer (score -1):

The ultimate cause resides here:

```
new File(files.get(i).getName())
```

`File.getName()` returns the last portion of the file's path, so the newly created file basically looses all path information.

The resulting path most probably does not exist which makes `convertJson(File)` return `null`, which is passed into `List<Student> students` and from there to `toCSV(List)`, where finally the NPE occurs.

---

Possible fix:

```
Student temp = fiel.convertJson(files.get(i));
```

Comment: A file or path not existing should not cause a `NullPointerException`. A far better fix would be to let `convertJson()` throw the `FileNotFoundException` back to the caller.

Comment: @EJP That's totally not a fix, because then there's a `FileNotFoundException` for a file that was seemingly listed while reading a directory. It is however an improvement in design, so feel free to post it as a comment to the question.